# using Jinja to extract json field into a table

Tags: json, jinja2

not sure if this is possible or not in Jinja but I have JSON output that has a field with a comma separated list of values e.g.

{"InvestigationName":"User reported message as malicious 'Rules of Conduct' for 'Phish'","Status":"No threats found","ProcessedBySentinel":"True","Alert generation status":"Full alert created"}

and I want to use jinja to display this detail in a table

is there a way to do this??

Comment: That looks like a JSON object, not a comma separated list of files. Can you clarify what you're trying to do? Are you working with Python, or Ansible, or something else?

Comment: so I am working with an application that pulls in alert data from various SIEMs and lets you build workflows around them. the workflow builder has a jinja template engine built in and we use that for things like pulling in alert data as a JSON object and then looping through the object to spit the fields out into a formatted table. The issue I am trying to solve now is that for some alerts the JSON object has this one field called extended properties that contains all the important alert data in field:value pairs and I am asking if I can use jinja to extract those into a table

Comment: or is there a way to extract specific field:value pairs from the string. in my example its really just the Investigation Name and Status that i want.

Comment: Still not clear what you're trying to do. I don't see an "extended properties" field in your example. It would help to see the code you're currently using to parse the response from the server. It looks like you should just be decoding the JSON into a Python dictionary and then referencing the specific keys in which you're interested, but there's not enough information here for me to be certain that's the right suggestion.